# Editor placeholder in source file. Can anyone help me fixing this bug? (I've attached pic, need to create same app)

Tags: swift, xcode

[need to create same app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPWUG.png)Can anyone help me with the below error?

[image: can anyone help?]

I am trying to pass data in the table view cell from another view controller. feeling stuck. I am a beginner.

Comment: we can not help you unless you give us more details

Comment: I've added image

Comment: @PrinceOberoi look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

There is a `placeholder` in the file. It is very clear. You have to add a `ViewController()` in its place.

```
self.navigationController.pushViewController(nextVC(),animated: true) //Here nextVC is your view controller to which you want to go to.
```

Comment: Cannot convert value of type 'TableViewCell.Type' to expected argument type 'UIViewController' , I get this after adding view controller

Comment: You can not conform a `TableViewCell` to a `UIViewController` type.

Comment: Can you join me on skype or anydesk? It is very urgent. I am making a journal app.

Comment: Nope. You can initiate a chat here.

Comment: this tableviewcell is a swift file, ok what I want is to save entries without using core data in table view? guide me. and tell when to apply MVC in project?

Comment: Do you know what MVC is?

Comment: yes, not worked on it yet, but i read about it. Can i apply it at the end of project?

Comment: End? No, you have to build in that design pattern from the beginning. When we develop an app or website, we follow a design pattern which can be `MVC`,`MVVM` etc.

Comment: now what if I've almost completed my project and not applied mvc yet.